# jQuery file in Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2.

I am using a slider on the home page, that requires `jquery.bxslider.min.js`. I am not sure where to store this file, or how to call it.

Comment: Grammatical fixes

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

According to Magento 2 standard you can put custom js in a Module or in a Theme

**Theme**

```
[theme_dir]/web/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js
+ [theme_dir]/requirejs-config.js
```

**Module**

```
[module_dir]/view/frontend/web/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js
+ [module_dir]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

In both cases you will need to create a requirejs-config.js

**For Module**

```
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           bxslider: '[Companyname_Modulename]/js/jquery.bxslider.min',
       }
   }
};
```

also read official dev-guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html

**EDIT**

Steps to add custom js into theme

1. Edit [theme_dir]/requirejs-config.js add these lines

```js
var config = {

    deps: [
        "js/main",
    ],

    map: {
        '*': {
            'bxslider': '/js/jquery.bxslider.min'
        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "bxslider": ["jquery"]
    }
};
```

2. Create file [theme_dir]/web/js/main.js add initialization code for your slider

```js
define([
    "jquery",
    "bxslider"
],
function($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function($){
        // Initialization of bxslider
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            captions: true,
            slideWidth: 600
        });
    });
    return;
});
```

3. Finally add bxslider lib into theme's js folder

   [theme_dir]/web/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js

Comment: I have jquery file that only I want to use. Could you tell me the proper steps of that.

Comment: whether to use theme of module method depends on what you want. the most simple way would be using your custom theme. i will add some steps into my answer